# Scroll horizontal no muestra los controles

Tags: c#, scrollbar

Tengo un form padre y dentro de este muestro los demas forms hijos, esto va bien, el problema es que dentro de algunos forms hijos tengo algunos dashboards, el problema es que cuando el form padre lo abro en su tamaño original (1650,600) no se visualizan todos los datos del dashboard por ello opte por agregar un scroll bar horizontal para cuando esta el form padre abierto en su tamaño original se muestre el Scrool y el usuario puede desplazarse para ver los demas datos que no son visibles, cuando se maximize el form padre entonces quito la Scrool Bar ya que asi si se ven todos los datos. El problema que tengo es que el scrool bar se desplaza pero no muestra los datos que hacen falta es decir el panel donde estan los Datos se queda estatico.

Agrego imagenes y el codigo que estoy usando:

[image: Modo diseño del panel del dash]

[image: Run App del Dash]

```
 private void ScrollActivo()
    {
            //pnlDashboard.Controls.Clear();
            pnlDashboard.AutoScroll = false;
            //pnlDashboard.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
            pnlDashboard.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;

            pnlDashboard.AutoScroll = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Maximizado");

        

        ScrollBar hScrollBar1 = new HScrollBar();
        //hScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        hScrollBar1.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
        
        hScrollBar1.Scroll += (sender, e) => { pnlDashboard.HorizontalScroll.Value = hScrollBar1.Value; };
        pnlDashboard.Controls.Add(hScrollBar1);
    }
```

Alguna idea de como solucionar el problema?

Saludos

DS

Comment: Que es esto?? WPF, UWP, win forms, etc???

Comment: @Yussef es Windows Forms